# Twitter Bootstrap, dropdown border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can see this in Chrome at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns. Basically, if you click on dropdown link twice (to open and then close the submenu), there's a yellowish border around the menu item which looks strange. I can't find in CSS where it is set, so the question is how can I remove it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an outline that your browser inserts by default.

Try to insert in your css

```
a.dropdown-toggle { outline: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is not a setting in your browser? 
I can not replicate this issue at my end. 
Try changing your browser and check if problem persists.

It seems like a browser issue.

Comment: i get it too (chrome), if you open and close, and mouseout an yellow outline comes visible and if you hover it it's gone.

Comment: The border is different in other browser (tried in IE), but it's still there. This has to do with the outline setting. chumkiu's answer helped.

Answer (score -2):

It could be caused by poor display or problem with your VGA output. I'm not experiencing any of symptoms you mentioned, but, based on my experience, could be caused by one of those two. You might want to consider re-installing or updating VGA driver, or playing around with settings such as gamma, brightness, or so.

Hope it helps.